# Recursively search xml by entry

Tags: python, xml

I have a feed of XML from Google, about 300 entries in all. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<ns0:feed ns1:etag="W/"LIESANDCRAPfyt7I2A9WhHERE."" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:ns2="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <ns0:updated>2012-01-25T14:52:12.867Z</ns0:updated>
    <ns0:category term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#profile" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"/>
    <ns0:id>domain.com</ns0:id>
    <ns0:generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</ns0:generator>
    <ns0:author>
        <ns0:name>domain.com</ns0:name>
    </ns0:author>
    <ns0:link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://www.google.com/"/>
    <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full"/>
    <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/batch"/>
    <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full?max-results=300"/>
    <ns2:startIndex>1</ns2:startIndex>
    <ns2:itemsPerPage>300</ns2:itemsPerPage>
    <ns0:entry ns1:etag=""CRAPQR4KTit7I2A4"">
        <ns0:category term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#profile" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"/>
        <ns0:id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson</ns0:id>
        <ns1:name>
            <ns1:familyName>Person</ns1:familyName>
            <ns1:fullName>Name Person</ns1:fullName>
            <ns1:givenName>Name</ns1:givenName>
        </ns1:name>
        <ns0:updated>2012-01-25T14:52:13.081Z</ns0:updated>
        <ns1:organization rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true">
            <ns1:orgTitle>JobField</ns1:orgTitle>
            <ns1:orgDepartment>DepartmentField</ns1:orgDepartment>
            <ns1:orgName>CompanyField</ns1:orgName>
        </ns1:organization>
        <ns3:status indexed="true"/>
        <ns0:title>Name Person</ns0:title>
        <ns0:link type="image/*" rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/profile/domain.com/nperson"/>
        <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson"/>
        <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="edit" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson"/>
        <ns1:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" address="nperson@gapps.domain.com"/>
        <ns1:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" primary="true" address="nperson@domain.com"/>
        <ns4:edited>2012-01-25T14:52:13.081Z</ns4:edited>
    </ns0:entry>
    <ns0:title>domain.com's Profiles</ns0:title>
</ns0:feed>
```

i am able to pull the data form the name, organization and email fields with beautifulstonesoup with this code:

```
profiles_feed = gd_client.GetProfilesFeed('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full?max-results=300')

soup = BeautifulSoup(str(profiles_feed))


for tag in soup.findAll('ns1:name'):
    print tag.find('ns1:familyname').text
    print tag.find('ns1:fullname').text
    print tag.find('ns1:givenname').text

for tag in soup.findAll('ns1:organization'):
    print tag.find('ns1:orgtitle').text
    print tag.find('ns1:orgdepartment').text
    print tag.find('ns1:orgname').text

for tag in soup.findAll('ns1:email',address=True):
    print tag['address']
```

I want to be able to grab the data group together from every ns0:entry node, so it would output a line like: family name, given name, org title, org name, email

I have tried using:

```
for tag in soup('ns0:entry'):
    print tag.name.familyName.text
```

But it treats it as an attribute

I thought about using xpath, but I couldn't find any docs pertaining to beautifulstonesoup and xpath, so I am not sure it supports it native. So, how could i search each entry node and return all the data specific for the entry, instead of all of it grouped by tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
>>> xml = """<ns0:feed ns1:etag="W/"LIESANDCRAPfyt7I2A9WhHERE."" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:ns2="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
...             <ns0:updated>2012-01-25T14:52:12.867Z</ns0:updated>
...             <ns0:category term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#profile" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"/>
...             <ns0:id>domain.com</ns0:id>
...             <ns0:generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</ns0:generator>
...             <ns0:author>
...                 <ns0:name>domain.com</ns0:name>
...             </ns0:author>
...             <ns0:link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://www.google.com/"/>
...             <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full"/>
...             <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/batch"/>
...             <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full?max-results=300"/>
...             <ns2:startIndex>1</ns2:startIndex>
...             <ns2:itemsPerPage>300</ns2:itemsPerPage>
...             <ns0:entry ns1:etag=""CRAPQR4KTit7I2A4"">
...                 <ns0:category term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#profile" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"/>
...                 <ns0:id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson</ns0:id>
...                 <ns1:name>
...                     <ns1:familyName>Person</ns1:familyName>
...                     <ns1:fullName>Name Person</ns1:fullName>
...                     <ns1:givenName>Name</ns1:givenName>
...                 </ns1:name>
...                 <ns0:updated>2012-01-25T14:52:13.081Z</ns0:updated>
...                 <ns1:organization rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true">
...                     <ns1:orgTitle>JobField</ns1:orgTitle>
...                     <ns1:orgDepartment>DepartmentField</ns1:orgDepartment>
...                     <ns1:orgName>CompanyField</ns1:orgName>
...                 </ns1:organization>
...                 <ns3:status indexed="true"/>
...                 <ns0:title>Name Person</ns0:title>
...                 <ns0:link type="image/*" rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/profile/domain.com/nperson"/>
...                 <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson"/>
...                 <ns0:link type="application/atom+xml" rel="edit" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full/nperson"/>
...                 <ns1:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" address="nperson@gapps.domain.com"/>
...                 <ns1:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" primary="true" address="nperson@domain.com"/>
...                 <ns4:edited>2012-01-25T14:52:13.081Z</ns4:edited>
...             </ns0:entry>
...             <ns0:title>domain.com's Profiles</ns0:title>
...         </ns0:feed>"""
```

Note from the docs (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing XML):

> The most common shortcoming of BeautifulStoneSoup is that it doesn't know about self-closing tags. HTML has a fixed set of self-closing tags, but with XML it depends on what the DTD says. You can tell BeautifulStoneSoup that certain tags are self-closing by passing in their names as the selfClosingTags argument to the constructor:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml, selfClosingTags=['ns0:category','ns3:status', 'ns0:link','ns1:email'])
>>> a = soup.findAll('ns0:entry')
>>> a[0].find('ns1:familyname')
<ns1:familyname>Person</ns1:familyname>
>>> a[0].find('ns1:familyname').text
u'Person'
>>> a[0].find('ns1:givenname')
<ns1:givenname>Name</ns1:givenname>
>>> a[0].find('ns1:givenname').text
u'Name'
>>> for entry in a:
...     print ', '.join([entry.find('ns1:familyname').text, entry.find('ns1:givenname').text, entry.find('ns1:orgtitle').text, entry.find('ns1:orgname').text, entry.find('ns1:email')['address']])
...
Person, Name, JobField, CompanyField, nperson@gapps.domain.com
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks for helping me clear this up. Just one question; The parser stops when it find an empty attrib, I couldn't find anything in the docs for this, do you know if there is a flag to ignore empty attribs and tags?

Comment: `entry.find('ns1:email').get('address','No-address-found')` you can alter the `'No-address-found'` to be any string you want. See: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: I am sorry, i should have been more specific, if a text field is blank, the attrib to an address field would most likely not be blank in the xml I would be using, but the text fields in something like orgname might.

Comment: You can check if find returns None, if it doesn't do something with `text`: `if a[0].find('ns1:familyname') != None: print a[0].find('ns1:familyname').text`

Comment: I have been trying for a week to get this to work, but I cannot seem to get the parser to skip over NoneType. I have it written like this for entry in a:
 writer.writerow([entry.find('ns1:familyname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:givenname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:fullname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgtitle').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgdepartment').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:email',primary=True)['address']]) and it works fine, but if I try to add and condionals, it breaks. What am I missing?